Travelling to France for business using tourist Schengen visa
Recently I travelled to Switzerland on a Schengen tourist visa - type c.
I now have a requirement to travel to France for business purpose.
My schengen tourist visa is multi entry and has required number of days on it.
Can someone please help confirm if I can use the same visa for France travel or should I go for restamping.
